# Failed to read CouchDb schema from classpath

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, ektorp

I am using this guide to configure CouchDb via Spring-boot: [link](https://helun.github.io/Ektorp/reference_documentation.html#d100e1161). The problem arises when this XML configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:couchdb="http://www.ektorp.org/schema/couchdb"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.ektorp.org/schema/couchdb http://www.ektorp.org/schema/couchdb/couchdb.xsd
">

 <couchdb:database name="myDatabase" url="http://localhost:5984"/> 


</beans>
```

cannot be validated, because **ektorp** xml schema can't be read. When I check via browser link of its schema, there isn't any, but there is one definitively in maven dependencies. But when I switch this line

```
http://www.ektorp.org/schema/couchdb/couchdb.xsd
```

into

```
classpath:couchdb.xsd
```

It won't be read either, even it's in one of the maven dependencies under the name couchdb.xsd. (You can inspect that file on [github](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp/blob/master/org.ektorp.spring/src/main/resources/org/ektorp/spring/xml/couchdb.xsd)).

How I can force XML reader to look into maven dependencies in order to find proper schema file?

Comment: Since you are having issues with the XML configuration, is the XML configuration mandatory or you can configure it with a Spring-Bean Config class?

Comment: It was preferable way to configure it in XML. Anyway, I solved problem, look in answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is annoying like every other which occurs because of Eclipse's bugs. I just deleted config file and created it again, but **without to validate** xml schema, and everything works fine.

P.S. Configuration in the question is correct, there is no need to pull xml schema from local maven repository, i.e. from classpath.